# What should an asylee do when a Green Card comes NOT "1 year backdated"?

Tags: immigration

Based on USCIS regulation **"The date of adjustment for approved applications filed by asylees shall be one year prior to the date of being approved for permanent residence"**
Here is the link to that regulation https://www.uscis.gov/policymanual/Print/PolicyManual-Volume7-PartM.html#S-G

I became a permanent resident based on being an asylee. But my green card came with the "Resident Since" date equaling to my "Permanent Residence Application Approval" date, i.e. not "1 year backdated". What should I do? I have two options:

1) File form I90. Apply for a new card, and request the "Resident Since" date to be backdated

2) Do nothing. Wait. Four years from now, apply for naturalization and attach an explanation of why I'm applying after 4 years and not 5 years.

**Which option is the best?**

Note: It is important to have the "Resident Since" date backdated because this allows for an earlier Naturalization

Answer (score 3):

File I-90 to apply for a replacement green card, since some information on the card is wrong. You will not have to pay a fee because you will select the reason being the information is wrong due to a USCIS error.